# Returned object by function is empty

Tags: javascript, http, single-page-application, factory

I want return object with some data, but when I try return 'doc' variable, this variable is empty object.

here is my code:

```
myApp.factory('serviceDocuments', function serviceDocuments($http) {
    var doc = {};
    return {
        getDocument: function (data) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/getDocument',
                data: data
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                doc = response.data[0];
                // in this place doc variable has needed data
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log("ups... ;(");
            });
            // in this place doc variable is empty object
            return doc;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: That is how asynchronous calls work. You order a delivery pizza and you try to eat it once the submit button is pressed.

Comment: @epascarello . Very nice metaphor.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is asynchronous.  The line `return doc` is invoked before the callback for your http call (`doc = response.data[0]`).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18776339)

Comment: What are you talking about @7urkm3n, He is right.
OP's problem is the described above.